# Python- Removing items

Tags: python, genetic

I want to remove item from a list called mom. I have another list called cut

```
mom= [[0,8,1], [0, 6, 2, 7], [0, 11, 12, 3, 9], [0, 5, 4, 10]]
cut =[0, 9, 8, 2]
```

How do I remove what in cut from mom, except for zero?

My desire result is

```
mom=[[0,1],[0,6,7],[0,11,12,3],[0,5,4,10]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> [[e for e in l if e not in cut or e == 0] for l in mom]
[[0, 1], [0, 6, 7], [0, 11, 12, 3], [0, 5, 4, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it with List comprehension.

```
mom= [[0,8,1], [0, 6, 2, 7], [0, 11, 12, 3, 9], [0, 5, 4, 10]]
cut =[0, 9, 8, 2]
mom = [[x for x in subList if x not in cut or x == 0 ] for subList in mom ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided by Ingnacio and Dom are perfect. The same can be done in a more clear and easy to understand way. Try the following:

mom= [[0,8,1], [0, 6, 2, 7], [0, 11, 12, 3, 9], [0, 5, 4, 10]]

```
cut =[0, 9, 8, 2]

for e in mom:



for f in e:


if f in cut and f != 0:


e.remove(f)  #used the remove() function of list

print(mom)
```

Much easier for a novice in Python. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Given the cut=[0,9,8,2] and 
mom = [[0,8,1], [0, 6, 2, 7], [0, 11, 12, 3, 9], [0, 5, 4, 10]]

Assuming 0 element is removed from cut list

cut=[9,8,2]

result =[]
for e in mom:
     result.append(list(set(e)-set(cut)))

o/p
result

[[0, 1], [0, 6, 7], [0, 11, 3, 12], [0, 10, 4, 5]]